# Network with three-dimensional edgelist?

Tags: r, igraph, network-analysis, sna, statnet

I have data which provides information on flows by actor c, broken down by inputs originating from source s, to partner p.

Network data normally has only one information: Data / Information flows from A->B, B->C etc.

However, my data shows which flows from A->B then goes to C, and which from A->B goes to D.

The data is structured as a three-column edgelist.

```
source <- c("A", "D", "B", "B")
country <- c("B", "B", "A", "A")
partner <- c("C", "C", "C", "D")
value <- c("5", "0", "2", "4")

df <- data.frame(source, country, partner, value)

df
```

I kinda dont see how it would be possible to use this as network data - however, if anyone got an idea on how to use that way more fine-grained network that be amazing ((:

best,

moritz

Comment: hi, @zx8754, I just specified the question. is it clear what I mean?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 3D, it is still a flow, A to B then either C or D

Comment: yes that is two rows, however, with three columms. 
A->B->C
A->B->D

My question was how to convert that kind of data to a network / graph object. 

As far as I know, only n per n adjacency matrices or two-columm edgelists can be imported. 

sry for being too unspecific

Comment: Is it always 3 columns and then a value?

Comment: yes, that is the format

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this:

```
library(igraph)

g <- graph_from_data_frame(
  rbind(
    setNames(df[, c(1, 2, 4)], c("from", "to", "value")),
    setNames(df[, c(1, 3, 4)], c("from", "to", "value"))
  )
)

plot(g)
```

[image]

Comment: heya, thanks for the code! yes, that's a way of how get the data mapped - but if I am not mistaken the information stored in the df gets lost, namely that certain flows pass from S through C to P. I kinda think iGraph etc is not really able to represent the information.. fyi it is data from in- and output tables that i am trying to leverage

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if the code below is what you want

```
library(igraph)
v <- c(3,1)
g <- Reduce(union,lapply(v, function(k) graph_from_data_frame(df[-k])))
```

such that `plot(g)` gives

[image]

Comment: hi thomas, thanks for the reply! yes, that's a way of how get the data mapped - but if I am not mistaken the information stored in the df gets lost, namely that certain flows pass from S through C to P. I kinda think iGraph etc is not really able to represent the information.. fyi it is data from in- and output tables that i am trying to leverage

Comment: @lupo404 I am still feeling confused. Could you show your expected output and explain a bit?